# React Testing library: TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my Container using react-testing-library.

```
const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument({})];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

const storeState = {
 articles: 
    [
        {
            id: "9b565b11-7311-5b5e-a699-97873dffb364",
            title: "jsdhahd",
            body: "jsahdjadshajhd",
            link: "https://www.google.com",
            media: "media.jpg"
        },
    ],
loading: false,
error: ''
};

describe('<Homepage />', () => {
  let store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(storeState);
});

afterEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
});

it('should render correctly', () => {
    const container = render(<Provider store={store}>{<Homepage />}</Provider>);

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

And I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2DCN.png)

Can anyone help? 
It seems a problem with mocking the redux store, but I don't know exactly how to solve it.
I have in the reducer a initial state with the articles, loading, and error. 
And in my App.js file I'm wrapping the `<App/>` with the `<Provider store={store}>`

```
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was on the way I was creating the `storeState` object.

Correct way:

```
const storeState = {
   reducer: {
      articles: 
        [
         {
            id: "9b565b11-7311-5b5e-a699-97873dffb364",
            title: "jsdhahd",
            body: "jsahdjadshajhd",
            link: "https://www.google.com",
            media: "media.jpg"
        },
       ],
     loading: false,
     error: ''
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `state.articles` instead of `state.reducer.articles` in the `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: It can't be, because, otherwise, I'm not able to get the values stored on the reducer, to render my data on the app.